# 301 redirect with django / apache (httpd.conf) for slugs

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-301, httpd.conf

So I'm redirecting two things. One is SSL and domains and I have a static app with an .httaccess that does this:

```
# https/domain forwarding
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.org$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This seems to work. for example if I test `curl -I http://mydomain.com/` I get,

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 07 Jun 2013 11:43:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.mydomain.com/
```

and it works on the browser too.  However I also want to redirect

http://www.mydomain.com/**cat/some-category**/some-long-slug

==> https://www.mydomain.com/**category/name**/some-long-slug`

so to avoid redirect loops, I've edited the apache httpd.conf like so:

```
<Location "/cat/used-cars/">
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^www.mydomain.com/cat/used-cars/$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/category/cars/$1 [R=301,NC]    
</Location>
```

however when I test it with curl -I http://mydomain.com/cat/used-cars/
I see:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 07 Jun 2013 11:48:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.mydomain.com/car/used-cars/
```

So it knows it has to redirect but it doesn't? The browser gives a 404 as that address doesn't exist anymore.  Any tips as to what I might be doing wrong are very welcome.